# Why do some Process ID's in top have a - next to them?

Tags: macos, terminal

When you enter top in the terminal, I noticed that some PID's have a - like com.apple.qtkits.
Why is that, since I can't find anything about it in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page mentions this:

The pid field displays the following for the architecture: + for 64-bit native architecture, or - for 32-bit native architecture, or * for a non-native architecture.

That doesn't match my experience of seeing a - on some, and nothing on the rest. Perhaps no flag at all means "the default architecture."